# Client unable to connect to local C server

Tags: c, sockets

I am practising socket programming with a very basic exercise: building a server-client system.

The server is working properly (I tested it with telnet) and the code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#define syscall_error(msg, errno) \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", msg, errno); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
#define gen_error(msg) \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);   \
    return -3;

#define PORT 1313
#define BACKLOG 10

int main(){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET lst, acp;
    int errno;
    struct sockaddr_in host, client;
    socklen_t client_size;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0){
        gen_error("Failed to init winsock");
    }
    if((lst = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        syscall_error("SOCKET:", lst);
    }

    host.sin_family = AF_INET;
    host.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    host.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    memset(&(host.sin_zero), '\0', sizeof(host.sin_zero));

    if((errno = bind(lst, (struct sockaddr *)&host, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) == -1){
        syscall_error("BIND:", errno);
    }
    if((errno = listen(lst, BACKLOG)) == -1){
        syscall_error("LISTEN:", errno);
    }

    printf("Waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1){
        client_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if((acp = accept(lst, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_size)) == -1){
            syscall_error("ACCEPT", acp);
        }
        printf("Got connection from %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));
    }

    if(closesocket(lst) == -1)
        gen_error("Failed to close the last socket");
}
```

The real problem tends to happen during client execution:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#define PORT "1313"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET cnt;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;

    if(--argc == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <hostname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to init winsocket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if((errno = getaddrinfo(*++argv, PORT, &hints, &res)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(errno));
        return 1;       
    }
    for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if((cnt = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set up socket\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(connect(cnt, (struct sockaddr *)&p, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            struct sockaddr_in *ip = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect to %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr));
        }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

Since I am still learning and I am not able to find and focus on the problem, can someone helps me to understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any useful answer.

Comment: "real problem tends to happen" What problem? What do you expect to happen? What do you observe instead?

Comment: As the server is programmed, when connection take place ‘printf("Got connection from %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));’ is executed. When I use telnet this happens, when instead I use my client this does not happen and the error message, ‘ fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect to %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr));’ is shown with the host ip. This is the problem I am not able to solve.

Comment: It's not `p` and it's certainly not `&p`. The sockaddr is somewhere in `p` but it's not `p`. And `&p` is certainly wrong because that's treating the *pointer* as the address!

Comment: In addition, use `perror`/`strerror` for diagnostic. "An error occurred" is a rather useless diagnostic message.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks a lot. I've substitute 1connect(cnt, (struct sockaddr *)&p, p->ai_addrlen` with `connect(cnt, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen` and now the client works fine.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Previously I used to use `perror()` to print errors. Thought this work properly only when I work on Linux. On window, where the following program was wrote and compiled `perror` always return me `No Error` as if `errno` was never set with the  error. That's why now I tend to use this form.

Comment: On Windows socket errors can be obtained with WSAGetLastError and FormatMessage, like here https://handsonnetworkprogramming.com/articles/socket-error-message-text/